# how to extract values from .properties file, having two values corresponding to one property name

Tags: java, properties, selenium-webdriver

how to extract values from .properties file, having two values corresponding to one property name
Example of property file is

```
iFrame=className=demo-frame

DateTextBox=id=datepicker

datePicker=xpath="//td[not(contains(@class,'ui-datepicker-other-month'))]/a[text()='"+value+"']"
```

Q: main help required for 3rd property as value contains special characters as well.

Comment: check the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737812/properties-file-with-a-list-as-the-value-for-an-individual-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your values comma-separated:

```
DateTextBox=id,datepicker
String[] dates = properties.getProperty("DateTextBox").split(",");
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do following property also work with it:                                    datePicker=xpath, "//td[not(contains(@class,'ui-datepicker-other-month'))]/a[text()='"+value+"']"                                                                                                    As it contains comma in 2nd value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `indexOf` methods to get the desired results:

```
prop.getProperty("datePicker").
    substring(prop.getProperty("datePicker").
        indexOf("=", prop.getProperty("datePicker").indexOf("="))+1)
```

In this second indexOf provides first occurence of `=` which is utilised by enclosing indexOf to start its search from returned index. This in turn provides index of second `=` thus makes easy to capture substring.

**P.S.** it will work for all keys in your properties file.