# How does the java.util.Properties work when getting a key?

Tags: java

A [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instance's attributes are directly addressable, e.g. `prop.myKey` returns the value associated with `myKey`. I want to replicate this behaviour.

How does it work?

There's nothing like Python's magic methods AFAIK in Java.

Specifically I want to create something like `Properties` but which supports list values. I don't want to add extra dependencies (e.g. commons) so just want the simplest way of adding this. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737812/properties-file-with-a-list-as-the-value-for-an-individual-key) and am trying to add it to a custom Properties class (I might subclass Properties, I don't mind either way).

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right, but do you want to make the key public?

Comment: Yes. It'll be loaded from a config file.

Comment: As the docs say, `Properties` extend `Hashtable<Object,Object>`. If you want to replicate the behaviour, you can use a `Map<String, List<YourClass>`

Comment: @QBrute No, because not all values are lists.

Comment: There is `prop.getProperty("myKey")` only - no object mapping. JAXB can map XML to java objects.

Comment: @QBrute please expand I don't see how that helps

Comment: Why not store your configuration in [properties format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-), so you can use the Properties class itself?

Comment: @JoopEggen getProperty returns a String.

Comment: Please you explain what you are actually asking! The property class implements a map interface - you give a key, and you receive a string value. That is all there is to this.

Comment: @VGR I am. It doesn't support lists.

Comment: @GhostCat I don't want a string. I want a list.

Comment: So you create your own `Mapy<String, List<Whatever>>`?

Comment: @GhostCat Example please. Still don't see how this helps me load list values from a properties file like in the linked answer.

Comment: Thing is: the property format doesnt know about lists. It only knows about strings. But there are zillions of ways to look at strings. So how are we supposed to know what exactly you need. I would suggest that *you* provide some code, and outline what exactly you need, and why. Beyond that, there are formats such as yaml that probably already do what you need (including existing yaml parsers for java).

Comment: I would create classes to contain your values (key and collection), add JAXB annotations, and simply (un)marshal them...

Comment: @GhostCat exactly like in the linked answer. `myKey.1=x (new line) myKey.2=y` both need combining into a list accessible at `myKey`

Comment: And you were already told that this isnt possible. The object dot field notation **only** works for compile time stuff. You cant have an object where you do ".1" - unless you define a class that has a public field named 1. Which is a) probably not valid syntax b) a bad idea anyway. So you probably better tell us about the **underlying** problem you intend to solve this way.

Comment: That's the config file format

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with a more specific problem? The question and the answer accepted don't really match ...

Comment: @AxelH I messed up. I forgot I'm working with groovy not java. So this whole question was a waste of time really since groovy implicitly calls the 'get' and 'put' methods on maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is **not** possible in Java.

In Java, the "layout" of a class is **fixed** at compile time.

When you want an object to allow for "x.y" access to a field, then your java source code must contain the declaration of y inside the X class.

You can't add fields to a class dynamically.

The Java way is to have a field of type List, and simply make calls such as

```
someList.get(1);
```

or something like that. Python is an **interpreter** that allows you to do such kind of "magic" at runtime. Java is statically typed, and does not.

And for the record, as there was mentioning of groovy: groovy is in fact a "fully dynamic" language (see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-typing-vs-dynamic-lang) for example). But the problem is: as soon as you start to exploit features that actually use that "last bit" of dynamics - then the only way to do that is by actually running the groovy interpreter inside the JVM. Which comes at quite some runtime cost (it is possible to also "compile" groovy scripts - which leads to much better performance but allows for less "dynamics" on the other hand).

Comment: My bad. It's groovy not java. Seems it does magic too :-(

Comment: @jbrown When you want the "full dynamic" magic of groovy, then that works by having their **interpreter** running inside the JVM. Of course that is possible, but it dramatically decreases execution speed.

Comment: Just say "make sure you're not using groovy" :-D

Comment: @jbrown Each tool has its place. Never say never. But I nonetheless enhanced my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Properties doesn't give you the behaviour you desire?

```
Properties a = new Properties();
List<String> listProperty = new ArrayList<>();
listProperty.add("value");
a.put("key", listProperty);
System.out.println(a.get("key"));
```

> > [value]

Comment: I'm loading this from a config file. So I need to implement a method to convert a string value in the config file to a list. Please see the answer I linked to above for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what format will the string value in the config file have? comma separated list?

Comment: No. key.1=x key.2=y exactly like in the linked answer.

Comment: the linked question seems slightly different as it states the properties are in the format...

A=APPLE
A=ALPHABET
A=ANT
B=BAT
B=BALL
B=BUS

In any case I think the solution you are looking for would be a custom class that extends Properties and overrides the load method to deal with particular use case.  Either that or a completely custom properties class

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't let you access properties by keys directly as though they were public instance fields of the `java.util.Properties` class (the way groovy or python make it easy).

You need to call the `getProperty` method:

```
prop.getProperty("myKey"); //Returns a string
```

Or, you can call the get method:

```
prop.get("myKey"); //this one returns a string but the return type is Object
```

With a properties instance, you can retrieve the set of keys:

```
prop.keySet(); // returns a set of strings used as keys
```

Comment: So how does the Properties class work? It extends HashTable yet it's possible to call `propInstance.myKey` directly.

Comment: @jbrown No, you can't do that. You can't access the property key directly or use the bracket notation

Answer (score 0):

Just use the usual [properties format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-).  You can store a list of values using a separator of your own choosing:

```
names: Stan,Kyle,Cartman,Kenny,Butters
```

And code can simply split them:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("names").split(","));
```

If your values might have a comma, use a different separator, such as a newline:

```
names: Stan\nKyle\nCartman\nKenny\nButters
```

Code:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("names").split("\n"));
```

The properties format allows continuation onto multiple lines.  You can use this to enhance readability:

```
names: \
    Stan\n\
    Kyle\n\
    Cartman\n\
    Kenny\n\
    Butters
```

Comment: I can't do that. The values are too complicated and can contain commas. I need e.g. myVal.1=x (new line) myVal.2=y both accessible under myVal

Comment: Can’t you use a newline as a separator?  If not that, there are many many other choices, including control characters which are literally intended to be field separators.

Comment: No I need to have separate keys for each list item.