# Java : How to load content of .properties file into Properties using spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Java 8 on spring framework. I have a properties file which has "=" separated values in it. I am trying to load the values of the properties file into a Property directly using spring annotation.
For example :
my Application.properites has:

```
cat=250
dog=560
lama=1000
donkey=650
```

And I have declared this properties file in my context.xml as :

```
<util:properties id="app_props"
                 location="classpath*:/application.properties" />
```

Now in my main class I am trying to load all of the values in Application.properites into

```
private Properties properties;
```

**So that properties.getProperty("cat") will return "250"**

Not sure how to do it. May I get any help on that?

Comment: Is this a new project or an update to a legacy one?

Comment: Have you tried annotating `properties` with `@Resource(name="app_props")`? The `util:properties` is not quite the correct way to initialize/load your "properties"; I would recommend you to look into `context:property-placeholder`, and then use `Environment` or `@Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your properties file as follows

> XML Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

      <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />

</beans>
```

> Java Config

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

> Using your properties as follows

```
@Value( "${jdbc.url}" )
private String jdbcUrl;
```

You can find a complete working solution in my GitHub repository

https://github.com/mirmdasif/springmvc/tree/master/springproperties

Comment: I ended up using spring boot. Similar way described above. Other good examples of similar issues: 1> https://www.boraji.com/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example ,   2> https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot ,  3> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737812/properties-file-with-a-list-as-the-value-for-an-individual-key